# Why is a Backslash followed by single quote required inside JavaScript/jQuery commenting

Tags: javascript

I was creating a small program which rotates the image 360 deg continuously using transform attribute of CSS3 and SetTimeout method of JavaScript. I was able to get the required result by searching across. Program is running fine, but I am unable to understand one thing:
Why inside setTimeout, do we need backslash fol;owed by single quote.

```
setTimeout('rotateAnimation(\'' + elem + '\', '+ speed + ')',speed);
```

Relevant full code is:
 Inside head script:

```
<script>
var degrees=0;
function rotateAnimation(elem, speed){
    var el=document.getElementById(elem);
    if(navigator.userAgent.match("Chrome")){
        el.style.WebkitTransform="rotate(" +degrees + "deg)";
        } else if(navigator.userAgent.match("Mozilla")){
            el.style.MozTransform="rotate(" +degrees + "deg)";
            }
    setTimeout('rotateAnimation(\'' + elem + '\', '+ speed + ')',speed);
    degrees++;
    if(degrees>359)
    degrees=0;
    }
</script>
```

Inside body:

```
<img id="img1" width="150px" height="150px" src="culture.png" />
<script>
rotateAnimation("img1", 200);
</script>
```

Comment: Because `"img"` is a string and `img` is a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslash is the escape character of many languages for strings. The backslash allows reserved characters to be typed into a string without using their reserved meaning. If you did not have the backslash the quotation mark would mark the end of the string rather than insert a quotation mark into the string.

The reason why there needs to be a quotation at all is because that parameter is a string parameter which requires quotation termination.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks DGS and Alvaro too. :)

Answer (score 1):

There're at least three wrong assumptions in your statement:

> Why do Backslash followed by single quote required inside jQuery commenting

- `\'` is not required
- The whole code snippet has nothing to do with jQuery
- That line is not a comment

I'd personally rewrite the line into this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    rotateAnimation(elem, speed);
}, speed);
```

It's cleaner and less error-prone.

Comment: Got it. This way is quite cleaner. Though I believe the code snippet has to do with jQuery/JavaScript.

Comment: @ParamveerSaini It's JavaScript but not jQuery. jQuery is *not* a synonym for JavaScript: it's a third-party library which you don't appear to be using.

Comment: Okey. I mostly use jQuery and JavaScript interchangeably despite of knowing the difference. You are the expert. :)